# Add to different calendars in Google Calendar

Tags: google-calendar

On Google Calendar, is it possible to switch which calendar I am currently adding an event to? I know I can go into the event after I have created it and change the color code and which calendar the event is placed in, but I would like to be able to click the calendar on the left and then add an event of that color to the master calendar shown in the main display of all calendars.

I find myself frequently shifting around appointments and creating new ones and it would be nice to minimize the time spent organizing. If there are hotkeys or something to change event to a different calendar, that would also work.

I would also be open to other calendar suggestions, but I assume Google Calendar is one of the best?

Answer (score 1):

> I would like to be able to click the calendar on the left and then add an event of that color to the master calendar shown in the main display of all calendars.

Simple enough. Click the arrow next to the calendar to pull up the calendar menu, then select "Create event on this calendar".

[image: calendar context menu]

You can also do this when creating the event with other means, but you need to be on the full event edit screen. The "Quick add" screen just adds to your default calendar. Click "Edit event" to get to the full edit screen.